# Error al Actualizar los script de php5 a php7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

disculpa por la molestia mis estimados y sabios programadores bueno tengo un pequeño error al momento de actualizar mis scripts de php 5 hacia php 7.

Estuve actualizando un pequeño contador de visitas y me da muchos errores en   algunas lineas a ver si me pueden ayudar gracias.

online.php

```
<?php

require_once('conn.php');

$time = 5 ;

$date = time() ;

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$limite = $date-$time*60 ;

mysql_query("delete from online where date < $limite") ;

$resp = mysql_query("select * from online where ip='$ip'") ;

if(mysql_num_rows($resp) != 0) {
mysql_query("update online set date='$date' where ip='$ip'") ;
}

else {
mysql_query("insert into online (date,ip) values ('$date','$ip')") ;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM online";

$resp = @mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$usuarios = mysql_num_rows($resp);

if($usuarios > 1 || $usuarios == 0){
    echo("Hay ");
    }else{
    echo("Hay ");
}if($usuarios == 0){
    echo("no ");
    }else{
    echo($usuarios." ");
}if($usuarios > 1 || $usuarios == 0){
    echo("Usuarios en línea.");
    }else{echo("usuario en línea.");
}?>
```

Visitas.php

```
<?php

include('conn.php');


$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];



$sql="select ip, TIMEDIFF(NOW(), fecha), fecha, num_visitas from visitas where ip='$ip'";



$rs=mysql_query($sql) or die("Problemas al ejecutar select SQL ".mysql_error());



$fila=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

$tiempo=$fila[1]; 

$num_visitas=$fila[3]; 

$horas_t=substr($tiempo,0,2); 

$tiemRes = 5; 

if (mysql_num_rows($rs)==0)

{

$sql="insert into visitas(ip, num_visitas, fecha) values('$ip', 1, NOW())";

mysql_query($sql) or die("Problemas al ejecutar la insert SQL ".mysql_error());

}



elseif (mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0 && $horas_t > $tiemRes)

{

$sql="update visitas set fecha=NOW(), num_visitas='$num_visitas'+1 where ip='$ip'";

mysql_query($sql) or die("Problemas al ejecutar update SQL ".mysql_error());

}

$sql="select SUM(num_visitas) from visitas"; 

$rs=mysql_query($sql) or die("Problemas al ejecutar select SQL ".mysql_error());

$fila=mysql_fetch_array($rs); 

$num_visitas=$fila[0]; 

mysql_close($conection); ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los errores que te muestra?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que sean tus funciones de conexión a la DB y ejecución de querys, fueron removidas en php7, lo cual deja camino a utilizar `mysqli` o `PDO`.

En esta liga de la función `mysql_connect`, te indica que fue marcada como deprecada desde php 5.5.0, y removida en php 7.0.0

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Tu flujo debería quedar de la siguiente manera

```
...
// creamos un objeto de conexión a la base de datos
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','usuario', 'password', 'database');
// generamos una sentencia preparada para ejecutar nuestra insercción de datos
$stament = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mitabla(?,?,?)");
// indicamos parametros a utilizar
// s - indica que la variable sera un string
// i - indica que la variable sera un integer
$stament->bind_param("ssi", $campo1, $campo2, $campo3);
// asignamos los valores a las variables, la forma de hacerlo de bind, es que toma las referencias de las variables
$campo1 = "VALOR";
$campo2 = "DESCRIPCIÓN";
$campo3 = 500;
// ejecutamos nuestra sentencia preparada
$statement->execute();
// verificamos si hubo filas afectadas
if($statement->affected_rows > 0)
    echo "El campo fue insertado";
// cerramos nuestra sentencia
$statement->close();
//cerramos nuestra conexión
$conn->close();
```

para mas info en la documentación

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Hola Hammerffall BK mi DB conexion esta con mysqli, pero estoy intentando actualizar todo las sentencias mysql por mysqli a pesar de poner a todos mysqli me sale errores en varias lineas pidiendo que mysqli esta mal definido, solo eso queri que me ayudaran a corregir.

Comment: Añade que error te marca.

Comment: podrías actualizar tu código, es probable que necesites mandar una opción extra a `mysqli_query` como puede ser la constante `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`la cual te devuelve el resultado y debes hacer una liberación con `mysqli_free_result()` una vez que hayas acabado con la consulta

Comment: Hola Hammerffall BK deja ahi el error mas arriba para que te fijes bien, voy a intentar con lo que me dices.

Comment: Gracias Hammerffall BK ahora leeré la documentación y seguiré practicando con el ejemplo que me brindaste.